# What is the motivation behind requiring LPGA Tour members to speak English?

Tags: terminology, lpga-tour

Effective at the end of 2009, LPGA Tour golfers on the tour for two years were required to pass an English oral evaluation exam or face suspension<sub>[(1)](http://sports.espn.go.com/golf/news/story?id=3553888)</sub>.

Looking at the *current* [Women's World Golf Rankings](http://www.rolexrankings.com/en/rankings/), ten of the top 25 originate from Korea. Does the presence/prevalence of golfers from countries where English is not the native language a factor in this requirement?

**What is the motivation behind requiring LPGA Tour members to speak English?**

Comment: The LPGA [softened their stance considerably](http://sports.espn.go.com/golf/news/story?id=3570957) less than two weeks after the initial announcement.

Comment: The most likely reason is that the players need to understand the course officials during a match, and the officials probably only speak English.

Comment: I have given the "official reason" in my answer below, but the "real reason" will only be guess work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Official statement,

> Why now? Athletes now have more responsibilities and we want to help their professional development," deputy commissioner Libba Galloway told The
> Associated Press. "There are more fans, more media and more sponsors. We
> want to help our athletes as best we can succeed off the golf course as well
> as on it."

via [ESPN](http://sports.espn.go.com/golf/news/story?id=3553888).

Another official statement :

> LPGA Deputy Commissioner Libba Galloway, a graduate of Duke Law and a
> practicing attorney before joining the LPGA, disagrees: "We are not
> discouraging players from speaking other languages. They can talk to their
> caddie in whatever language they choose. They can speak to other players on
> the driving range in whatever language they choose. If they're Brazilian and
> a reporter asks them a question in Portuguese, by all means, answer it in
> Portuguese. And we're not demanding that the players be perfectly fluent in
> English. What we're saying is that the ability to speak to your pro-am
> partners and to the media, and for the winner to give their victory speech
> in English, will be one of our tournament regulations."

via [Golf.com](http://www.golf.com/tour-and-news/legal-questions-surround-lpgas-new-rule-requiring-players-speak-english).

Of course, the rule has since being revoked, which was mentioned in the comments.